# calling multiple functions in $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript functions that are used for different pages is it best to call all those functions (lets say 20 functions) inside the document.ready function E.g

```
function functionforpage1(){
    //do something on page1
}

function functionforpage2(){
    //do something on page2
}

function functionforpage3(){
    //do something on page3
}
```

...up to function 20

and i call them like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

functionforpage1();
functionforpage2();
functionforpage3()
functionforpage4()
................
functionforpage20()
})
```

is this advisable? and does it take effect on the performance of the pages, because if i load page 20 it will have to run through all the functions from 1- 19 before executing function 20. If not wise to do such what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

It might be preferable to have your code determine which functions are relevant to the page and only call those. For instance, perhaps by having your main JavaScript not use `ready` at all, and then have a small inline `script` block on each page that calls only the relevant one:

```
<!-- On page 3 -->
<script src="your-main-script.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(functionforpage3);
</script>
```

But assuming the functions figure out early that they aren't relevant (for instance, a simple DOM query), calling ~20 functions that each do a single DOM query and 19 of them stop because they see that they don't find what they're looking for isn't going to cause any noticeable problem. Just have them fail early and quickly.

Comment: Crowder thank you for your reply, is it advisable to use and if statement to determine the page name at least? and know if the page actually needs that function.

Comment: @chikor.net: I would try to avoid centralizing that knowledge, and instead keep that knowledge in the page (for instance, with the inline script above).